# event.ctrlKey is not functioning in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

```
$('a').click(function(event){
  if( event.ctrlKey || event.target.href){ 
   return false;
  }     
});
```

Working fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE. Please help in this.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `event.keyCode` instead?

use it as:

```
if( (event.keyCode == 17 ) || event.target.href ){
   return false;
}
```

Reference: [Javascript Char Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)